# I'm using xargs, but the argument list is too long

Tags: linux, xargs

I'm using Linux.  I have a directory tree with over 100,000 files that originated on a MS Windows system.  Some of the files have spaces in their names.  I want to convert those files to unix.  I ran this command

```
find . -type f | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

And received this error message

```
xargs: argument line too long
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `xargs -0` why did you use `-0`?

Comment: Because some files have spaces in their name.  If I don't use -0, then the command does not work properly.

Comment: Don't you need `-print0` in find?

Comment: on Microsoft Windows you may need to use '-s', as in: 'xargs -0 -s 20000' (refer to the man page for details) ... i learned this many years ago due to a bug in msysgit: https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/354#issuecomment-106244339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need xargs here, you can do

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix '{}' +
```

Comment: Okay that worked (with slight modifications to make it work for csh/tcsh).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `xargs` with `-0` to prevent issues with spaces/special characters in file names you must also use `-print0` with `find` so it will delimit its output with null bytes:

```sh
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```